# Finding the Voltage and Current rating of a switch

Tags: voltage, switches, current-rating

I just bought a couple of switches at a garage sale. One looks like a SPST switch and the other seems to be a DPST switch. No where on these switches does it show a Voltage / Current rating. How can I find out what the Voltage / Current rating is? These are printed on the side of the switch, but I have no idea what that means  [These are printed on the side of the switch, but I have no idea what that means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYAdL.jpg)!

Comment: Typically, the rating is provided on the datasheet used when the switch is sold. Without knowing the model number which will help you find the datasheet, you're probably out of luck, although you may be able to make an educated guess by looking at the construction of the switch.

Comment: Are serial numbers usually printed somewhere on the component? @nanofarad

Comment: Model numbers? Potentially but I wouldn't say "usually yes" or "usually no". Some forms (e.g. molded plastic) might make it easier to add an identifier as compared to e.g. bent sheet metal for the case. Serial numbers? Unlikely. Regardless, if you're working with trivial hobbyist voltages and currents (e.g. 5V, tens of mA) the switches will very likely handle it perfectly well, unless they are some kind of specialty switch.

Comment: I was wondering if I could use it for a 36V DC power supply, but probably not unless I find that data sheet I guess @nanofarad

Comment: I found about 50 small switches in one of my several storage locations. More than half of them have rating information printed or embossed on them. With a good light and a magnifying glass, I can read them. If you have an unmarked switch, you probably shouldn't use it for 36V DC. If a switch has a DC rating, the current rating is likely much less than the AC current rating.

Comment: The switch pictured in the added link looks like an old telephone switchboard switch.

Comment: Assuming it is a telephone switchboard component, it was designed to do exactly what it was used for and nothing else.

Comment: What current and load do you want to switch - above ~28V at moderate to high current with any inductance in the load is very hard on a switch.

Answer (score 1):

looks like an old-shoool leaf switch,

assuming it's old telephone equipmwent hardware, 60VDC or 120VAC and 200mA current seems a safe bet,